# Filters not updating template dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteorite

I am trying to filter my collection "PriceList" and successfully implemented sorting, which works perfectly fine, but when I tried to implement filters and search, it is acting strangely. When I click custom filter buttons, they dont update the template dymanically, but when I do sorting after that, template gets updated, any idea where I am doing mistake? The following are the files, let me know if any more information needed.

price_list.js

```
PriceListFilter = new Meteor.FilterCollections(PriceList, {
  name: "PriceListFC",
  template: 'price_list',
  filters: {
    "trip": {
      title: 'Trip Types',
      operator: ['$regex', 'i'],
      condition: '$and',
      searchable: 'optional',
    },
  }, 
  sort:{
    order: ['desc', 'asc'],
    amount0: ['desc', 'asc'],
    amount1: ['desc', 'asc'],
    amount2: ['desc', 'asc'],
    amount3: ['desc', 'asc'],
    amount4: ['desc', 'asc'],
  },
});
```

price_list.html

```
<template name="price_list">
<div class="pael panel-info">
  <div class="">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" value="{{fcFilterSearchable.criteria}}" data-fc-search-target="search-box">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success fc-search-trigger" data-fc-search-trigger="search-box">Submit</button>
        {{#each available}}
          <a href="#" class="fc-search-fields">{{#if active}}Disable{{else}}Enable{{/if}} {{title}} filter</a>
          {{/each}}
      <button type="button" class="fc-filter btn btn-primary {{#if fcFilterObj.isActive 'trip' 'Single Trip'}}active{{/if}}" data-fc-filter-field="trip" data-fc-filter-value="Single Trip" >
        Single Trip
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="fc-filter btn btn-primary {{#if fcFilterObj.isActive 'trip' 'Annual Trip'}}active{{/if}}" data-fc-filter-field="trip" data-fc-filter-value="Annual Trip" >
        Annual Trip
      </a>
        {{#if fcFilterSearchable.criteria}}<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger fc-search-clear">Reset</button>{{/if}}
      </form>
      {{#if fcFilterActive}}
      <div class="navbar-form pull-right">
        {{#each fcFilterActive}}
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info fc-filter-clear">{{title}}: {{operator}} {{value}}</a>
        {{/each}}
      </div>
      {{/if}}

   </div>
    <h4>Price Comparision</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead >
        <tr class="info">
          <th class="fc-sort" data-fc-sort="amount0">
            InsureandGo.com - Budget
            {{#if fcSort.amount0.desc}}(des){{/if}}
            {{#if fcSort.amount0.asc}}(asc){{/if}}
          </th>
          <th class="fc-sort" data-fc-sort="amount1">
            InsureandGo.com - Silver
            {{#if fcSort.amount1.desc}}(des){{/if}}
            {{#if fcSort.amount1.asc}}(asc){{/if}}
          </th>
          <th class="fc-sort" data-fc-sort="amount2">
            InsureandGo.com - Gold
            {{#if fcSort.amount2.desc}}(des){{/if}}
            {{#if fcSort.amount2.asc}}(asc){{/if}}
          </th>
          <th class="fc-sort" data-fc-sort="amount3">
            InsureandGo.com - Black
            {{#if fcSort.amount3.desc}}(des){{/if}}
            {{#if fcSort.amount3.asc}}(asc){{/if}}
          </th>
          <th class="fc-sort" data-fc-sort="amount4">
            InsureandGo.com - Annual Silver
            {{#if fcSort.amount4.desc}}(des){{/if}}
            {{#if fcSort.amount4.asc}}(asc){{/if}}
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {{#each fcResults}}
      <tr>
        <td>{{amount0}}</td>
        <td>{{amount1}}</td>
        <td>{{amount2}}</td>
        <td>{{amount3}}</td>
        <td>{{amount4}}</td>
      </tr>
      {{/each}}
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using `fcPager` along with `fcSort` in your template, then the template helper dependencies don't get invalidated when the data changes—possibly due to a `Dependency` initialization quirk in `filter-collections`.

Try adding a paginator to your template. Otherwise you can try overriding the template listeners and forcing invalidation with [`changed()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#dependency_changed)